# Moon changes position

Tags: the-moon

So most nights the Moon usually rises on the right of the sky when I look through the window just like the previous night.

But this night the Moon was on the left of the sky rising. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Also what you call left of the sky should rather be left to your window.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of any detailed information, such as @Uhoh asks for, this is just a guess, but here goes. I'm assuming you live at mid northern latitude.

The moon rises between south east and north east.  If we consider full moons, then during  the summer, the full moon will rise in the south east.  As we move into the autumn and winter, the full moon progressively rises further north.  If you are looking out of an east facing window, then through mid May to mid July the moon will appear to rise to the right side of your window, but will gradually move northwards, ie to the left of your window.

The reason behind this is that at full moon, the moon is diametrically opposite the sun.  At mid summer, the sun rises in the north east, and in mid winter it rises in the south east.

Comment: Ok I appreciate your answer